# How can I reference a DLL regardless of version?

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-construction, reference, version

Okay, I am a heavy user of Telerik's library of controls, specifically for ASP.NET. However, there is a small bit of functionality which I wanted to add to some of the controls. Nowadays I can do this easy enough using Extension methods. So I wrote a small library which does exactly that. Obviously, this library needs to reference their DLL (`Telerik.Web.UI.dll`).

In the `My Project > References` page of my DLL project, I have a reference to `Telerik.Web.UI.dll`. For this reference, I have the **Specific Version** property set to False, because I don't want my library to care about what version of the Telerik DLL is being used. THIS is my problem though... the .NET compiler doesn't seem to honor this setting.

Case in point, I have a website which references both the Telerik DLL and mine. I updated the Telerik library to the latest version. Now when I try to run my website, I get:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2012.1.215.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

I fix this by going to my DLL project, recompiling it against the latest Telerik DLL, and then updating my DLL in the website. This is precisely what i *didn't* want to have to do every time I update Telerik's library. I ***thought*** that setting **Specific Version** to false would mean it would work with any version. No? Or am I ***completely*** misunderstanding what that setting does?

Answer (score 4):

You should look into using [`bindingRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) which will allow you to instruct .NET framework to use another version of assembly at **runtime** (i.e. if your project was compiled against version 1.0, it would still work with version 1.1, assuming there were no API changes).

`Specific Version` attribute only applies to compile-time assembly reference.

Comment: Ah, looked interesting. But from what I can tell from the MSDN link, it would still require me to touch my DLL project every time I update the Telerik DLL. The whole point of what I was trying to do was to NOT have to update my library project with each new Telerik version, unless something in the Telerik library *specifically broke* something in my code.

Comment: Yes, you'd still need to make changes to your web.config but no re-compilation of the dll would be required.

Comment: That actually winds up being MORE work now though, because I use these two libraries in many websites, so if I have to touch the web.config instead of the DLL, that's many places to touch instead of one. At least recompiling the DLL is a centralized change.

Comment: Another option is to override the default assembly loading behavior in `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event so that instead of throwing exception when particular dll version isn't found, it would load updated dll into AppDomain. Here is MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx